# Oracle: SELECT value from where clause as dummy table

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

after a lot of searching I unfortunately couldn't find a solution for the following task:

I need an Oracle-SQL-Query that returns the value from the WHERE-clause as the result value. This sounds easy, but I just couldn't find out how to achieve this.

Example (how it should be):

```
SELECT some_dummy_colum FROM some_dummy_table WHERE some_dummy_coumn = 'MY_VALUE';
```

Desired Result:

```
MY_VALUE
```

I know that I could write something like

```
SELECT 'MY_VALUE' FROM DUAL;
```

But in this case I cannot hard-code the 'MY_VALUE', it can only be provided in the WHERE-clause (not in the SELECT or FROM parts or elsewhere).

Is there any way to achieve this in Oracle?
Thanks in advance for ideas!

Comment: I think you need a subquery

Comment: Can you elaborate with example what you want to do exactly?

Comment: *I cannot hard-code the 'MY_VALUE', it can only be provided in the WHERE-clause (not in the SELECT or FROM parts or elsewhere)* Why not? This constraint looks completely arbitrary, so you better elaborate on it further.

Comment: I have an external program that produces SQL-queries from user-inputs. These user-inputs are visible in the query only from the where clause. I need to extract the provided values in order to be able to process them further.

Comment: Can't you capture the user input directly, independently of running a query? It isn't clear why you're trying to do anything in the database at all. Can you see the whole generated query, with the fixed value embedded (implying it isn't parameterised, which is a worry), or the statement with placeholders and the bind values, before it is executed? Or do you somehow only have access to the result set?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible in this case. I really need to get the restriction(s) out of the where clause as result fields... :-(

I can "see" the whole query, but I know in advance that the value that the user limits the query to, is not contained in the table. Nevertheless, I need to get this value the user wanted in order to insert it into a table later.

Comment: As stated isn't possible (I think), so please edit your question to explain the scenario and restrictions you have, and what you can influence. For instance how you actually supply and run the query, whether there are restrictions on how complicated the query can be, how the user input is supplied and fed into the query, exactly what you can see at each stage, etc. I can *maybe* think of a way if you're using (named) bind variables but at the moment it's just too vague.

Comment: If that is a `=` condition in the `where` clause, then the value will be in the column that is part of that condition. If that column is part of the `select` list, then you have that value already

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You are perfectly right as long as the value is found in the table. In my case, it will not be found but but I need it anyway.

Comment: How realistic is your posted query? Will it always be of the format `where col = 'some_value';`? Or will there be AND or OR conditions? IN or EXISTS conditions? Different datatypes beyond strings?

Comment: It should not get much more complex. The single restriction value is a string.

Comment: If you have access to the entire statement, with the value embedded in it as you've shown (not bound!), then can't you just parse it out of that string from within your application? I'm still unclear why you have to try to do this in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a really nasty hack, more for curiosity than anything:

```
select (
  select regexp_replace(vsql.sql_text,
    q'@.*where '(.*)' is not null@', '\1')
  from v$session vses
  join v$sql vsql
  on vsql.sql_id = vses.sql_id
  where vses.audsid = userenv('SESSIONID') 
) as result
from dual
where 'MY_VALUE' is not null
/

RESULT              
--------------------
MY_VALUE
```

Or without the subquery, if you can make the `where` clause more complicated:

```
select regexp_replace(vsql.sql_text,
  q'@.*and '(.*)' is not null@', '\1') as result
from v$session vses
join v$sql vsql
on vsql.sql_id = vses.sql_id
where vses.audsid = userenv('SESSIONID') 
and 'MY_VALUE2' is not null
/

RESULT              
--------------------
MY_VALUE2
```

Either way it's looking in the data dictionary for the statement that is currently being executed by this session; and I'm not entirely sure that's a valid thing to do. This seems to work in 11g and 12c, and (so far) always reports the value being searched for, but I don't know that it is guaranteed. It feels like an abuse of the space-time continuum...

Comment: @Ben - yes... I've just simplified it slightly to avoid rebuilding the full SQL statement with `listagg()`. I'm not sure I'd trust this in production code without doing a lot more research *8-)

Answer (score 0):

```
with t as 
(
select 'CHALKEG' as name from dual
)
select * from t where name = 'CHALKEG'
```

Comment: You can improve this answer by explaining why it solves the problem presented in the question.